# Privately communicate with a public elastic beanstalk loadbalancer

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I have two beanstalk applications deployed - an app and an api.  Both have public loadbalancers.  The instances and the loadbalancers are all in the same security groups: the default, self referencing vpc security group and a group which allows http access from a single IP.  They are both in the same VPC.  The two services are currently failing to communicate.  I expected them to be able to communicate by placing them in the same default SG.

I have SSHed onto an instance of the app and I have found that I can successfully curl an instance of the API, but I cannot curl the loadbalancer of the API.  I have found that if I add a security group with the public IPs of the app instances to the API load balancer I can successfully communicate, but not if I add just the private IPs.  My questions are therefore:

- If I add an instance to a self-referencing security group does it only allow the private IP through?
- While I would like my services to be publicly accessible to the single IP that I have allowed, I would prefer if they communicated between each other privately.  Is it possible to do that with a public loadbalancer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

2 days of learning later I think I can answer my question with what I've learnt:

- Self-referencing security groups only include the private IPs of the instances
- If a loadbalancer has a public dns, instances will communicate with it over the internet.
- You can find the loadbalancer's private IP address from the EC2 -> Network Interfaces interface, but I didn't go down this route because I can't automate that
- Instead I set my API beanstalk loadbalancer to be *internal*, along with a private zone matching the public zone.  This gets the traffic from the app to travel between the two environments privately and allows self-referencing security groups to be used.
- I then added an additional, public, loadbalancer to my API's beanstalk launch configuration, added a security group restricting the one IP I want to have access.  The public zone CNAME points at this.

This can all be automated.

Comment: I am trying to create this same setup, and I'm having trouble (I think) with setting up the zones correctly. Would you be able to go into more detail about that?

Comment: So I have two zones, both with the same domain name, one is private and one is public